# Segmentation fault running java program on raspberry pi

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, segmentation-fault, webcam, barcode-scanner

I am trying to run [this Java Program](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-qrcode/src/main/java/com/github/sarxos/example1/WebcamQRCodeExample.java) on my Raspberry Pi:

If i am executing the program it gives me the following error: 
I executed it by compiling it over eclipse on my windows PC and creating and executable jar

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ java -jar "/home/pi/Desktop/JarFiles/WebcamQRCodeExample.jar"[main] INFO com.github.sarxos.webcam.Webcam - WebcamDefaultDriver capture driver will be used
Speicherzugriffsfehler
```

"Speicherzugriffsfehler" is a segmentation fault in english

Every other java program works fine on my pi.
How do I have to change the code to solve this error?

Comment: UPDATE: I got the Code running now. My new Problem is now, that the program detects a QR-Code fine but does not react if I hold a EAN 13 barcode in front of it.
It works fine on Windows and can detect both there. 
Btw thank you for editing it :D